# Sorting in PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

While comparing ordering in PostgreSQL I came across a difference between a 9.1 install on Mac and a 8.4 install on Linux.

Here is the query.

```
select ']' > ', "y';
```

Returns `false`

However if I remove the y it looks like this.

```
select ']' > ', "';
```

Returns `true`

Does anyone have a suggestion.

Comment: Check you collation of databases and/or client. They might differ http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html

Comment: collation is en_US.UTF-8
I've also updated the Linux system to 9.1 
I guess I dont understand how removing the 4th character (the 'y') would make such a drastic change in the order. When the string on the left side is only one character.